# can i pass json data with a regular link in asp.net-mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

when i post using ajax, i can pass info into the data parameter which can be a json string.  Is there anyway to pass the same json string but without jquery and ajax to an asp.net-mvc controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
If you need to POST information back to the controller method, then I believe the only way to do this without jQuery or AJAX is using a `<form>`.

You could restyle the submit button as a link or something similar or even use jQuery to have some other event trigger the submit, but it wouldn't an AJAX request.

Assuming your returning the correct FileContentResult syntax/content then the browser should handle the download correctly.

HTH

---

I'm assuming you are wanting to test your AJAX method without jQuery?

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to call your MVC action with either GET or POST with any payload you wish.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts - i am actually have an ajax call that i am trying to return a file.  It doesn't seem to work so i am trying to convert it to a regular link.  My open question is how do a take what i am passing in today in the data parameter and get that to the server side ??

Comment: @Alastair Pitts  - im confused.  are you saying put this in a form post??

Comment: @ooo, yes. I *believe* that form POSTs are the only way to post back from a webpage outside of using AJAX/javascript.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts - so would i just shove my json string into a hidden field?? any other suggestions ??

Comment: @ooo: That would be the easiest method.

Comment: @ooo: It depends on how complex your JSON object is. If it's only a couple of attributes/fields, then separate hidden fields would work. If it's a large and complex JSON object, you could use JSON.net to parse the POSTed JSON string. Also, have a look at the link that Steve posted, it has information regarding JSON model binding.

Comment: @Alastair Pitts - thanks, i got it working using: DataContractJsonSerializer

Comment: @ooo: Awesome! Good to hear :)